# Allows to select on view, while hiding its definition

Tags: postgresql, permissions, security

I need to create a user in PostgreSQL with the least privileges possible. So, the user would only be allowed to do queries on specific tables and views. That user should not be allowed to get any additional info, especially not see the view definitions. How can this be done?

Comment: From where are you afraid that they might get information on the view definition?

Comment: The database is used in the backend of a web server. If the web server gets hacked, then the views could be accessed from there.

Comment: The backend connects to the database which is on a separate server.

Comment: What bad do you expect to happen if someone sees the view definition?

Comment: They could steal the views and use them themselves. Basically, imaging that these views are intellectual property that we want to protect.

Comment: I know it might sound strange, but it is a real use case. It doesn't really matter if the data gets stolen, it's public knowledge already. The thing that we really need to protect is the transformations used to create new data (which is also public knowledge). And fresh data comes in all the time, so moving the transformations to a separate database becomes a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot hide the view definition from the user without modifying the database metadata in a way that will break things. But it is no problem to show the user the view definition.

What is more important is to define the view with `security_barrier = true` so that the user cannot use functions with side effects to get at the underlying tables.

If you want to hide the query used to extract the data, your best choice might be to write a C function that produces the data. If the user has no access to the database server, that should be safe.

Comment: Does the same answer apply to materialised views?

Comment: @SavageReader Yes, it is the same for materialized views.